# Left Joining Tables in Qlik View

Tags: qlikview

I have loaded 2 tables in QlikView - TEAM and RESOURCE, and stored them in QVD format on disk. The tables can be seein in Table viewer.

Now I want to make another table TEAM_RESOURCE by left joining the two initial tables. I am having problems with that. What is the correct syntax? Is it better to use the tables loaded directly in QV, or the same tables stored in QVD format.

On Google I did not find best practices nor straightforward syntax examples.

Comment: There's a decent write up [here](http://www.qlikviewaddict.com/2012/03/explaining-joins.html) that should get you going.

Comment: Also see [THIS](https://community.qlik.com/blogs/qlikviewdesignblog/2012/09/12/to-join-or-not-to-join) and [THIS](https://community.qlik.com/blogs/qlikviewdesignblog/2012/09/18/one-favorite-function-applymap) for an alternative point of view from one of the Qlik technical leads.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to store information for later use, or if you have multiple models/qvws using the same data. For the latter you would use a generator qvw to extract and store qvds, and in the models use them.

If you only have one model, then rather not store qvd's as it defeats the purpose.

The correct syntax for joining tables within qlikview is the following:

```
LOAD
    Field1,
    Field2,
    Field3,
    KeyField
FROM aaa;

LEFT JOIN 

LOAD
    Field4,
    Field5,
    Field6,
    KeyField
FROM bbb;
```

The above would left join the last table to the previous, on the fields that have the exact same name (case sensitive)

The below would join to a specific previously loaded table:

```
Table1:
LOAD
    Field1,
    Field2,
    Field3,
    KeyField
FROM aaa;

LOAD
    Field 6,
    Field 7
FROM ccc;

LEFT JOIN (Table1)

LOAD
    Field4,
    Field5,
    Field6,
    KeyField
FROM bbb;
```

Comment: I did exactly the same, but I am not able to see the result table(the joined one in the data model viewer. Is it normal, or I need to add some sintax in my script. I need to note that I am using Qliksense , but for my knowledge sintax is same as Qlikview.